# Android - Using Picasso in order to load an image for a game?

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, android-glide

I have used both Picasso and Glide in order to load images asyncronously in grids with images coming from the phone's external memory and in order to download photos from the Internet.
But now for my Android game in the first screen I need to display an image below a title (the image takes up all available height). Then the user taps on a specific part of the image and the game starts.

The image content is a drawable resource.

So, for this specific use (a TextView and an ImageView below it which takes up all the remaining space), what should I do:

-Specify the image as ImageView's src property.

-Use an image loading library, such as Picasso or Glide

What do you suggest and why?

Thank you.

EDIT: The image would be static, a static drawable resource.

Comment: do you want the image to be dynamic??

Comment: No, it would be static, a static drawable resource

Comment: is the image too heavy i.e in comparison to your app size? If not, then since the image is so intrinsic to your app functionality, i would suggest adding it as an drawable resource, rather than loading it using Picasso.

Comment: The image is 320x480 in baseline density (mdpi). I thought it'd be the perfect size to display it taking all the available space below the TextView without pixelating, although I'm not sure if I picked up the best dimensions, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the image is static, there is no need to add third party libraries in your app. Do not depend on libraries too much. Keep it simple.